# Google Sheets API Access Token Expiry in React

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets, bearer-token, refresh-token

I would like to ask about a Google Sheets API integration issue I am facing. The requirement is to access a non-public Google Sheet, for which I use an access token. However, the problem is that the access token expires after 1 hour. My understanding is that using a refresh token might not be suitable in this scenario. I'm encountering a 401 error with the following code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getSheet() {
        const headers = {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_SHEET_TOKEN}`
        }
        const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_SHEET_URL, { headers })
        if (!response.ok) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // Need to refresh the token
                const refreshOptions = {
                    client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_ID,
                    client_secret: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    refresh_token: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_SHEET_REFRESH_TOKEN,
                    grant_type: 'refresh_token'
                }
                console.log('refreshOptions', refreshOptions)
                const fetchOptions = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(refreshOptions)
                }
                const refreshResponse = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token', fetchOptions)
                if (!refreshResponse.ok) {
                    console.warn('Token refresh failed')
                }
                console.log('Token refresh successful')
            }
            throw new Error(`Sheets request failed with status ${response.status}`)
        }
        const json = await response.json()
        setSheet(json)
    }
    getSheet()
}, []);
```